# проблема в выполнении скрипта JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Изучаю JS и уперся в проблему с JQuery, в скрипте есть несколько обработчиков событий и выполнятся только первый, остальные не работают. Два дня не могу понять в чем дело, решил просить помощи тут.

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var headerTxt = $('#headerTxt').val();
        var taskTxt = $('#taskTxt').val();
        if(headerTxt !=='') {
            $('#leftColumn h3').hide()
            var head = $('<h4></h4>').text(headerTxt);
            $(head).append('<button class="rem">X</button>');
            $('#task').append(head);
            $('#headerTxt').val("");
            if(taskTxt !=='') {
                var task = $('<p></p>').text(taskTxt);
                $('#task').append(task);
                $('#taskTxt').val("");
            };
        };
        
    });

    $('.rem').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().next('p').remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
            if ($('#task').text() == '') {
            $('#leftColumn h3').show();
            } else {
                $('#leftColumn h3').hide();
            }
        
    });

    $('#task h4').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').slideToggle();
        
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что другие обработчики у вас висят на элементы, которые динамически добавляются и на момент их "активации" элементов не существует на странице. Нужно пользоваться делегированием. Вешать обработчик на более верхний элемент, который никогда не меняется, не добавляется.

Например `$(document).on('click', '.rem', function(){` и `$(document).on('click', '#task h4', function(){`

В данном случае событие повешено непосредственно на документ, но лучше его вешать на элемент непосредственно самый близкий к элементам, к которым будет применяться событие

Подробнее про делегирование: [Прямая и делегированная обработка (параметр selector)](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29)

Comment: спасибо огромное, я понимал что в этом дело, но знаний и опыта пока не хватает, обязательно изучу тему делегирования!